# Как продолжить цикл for

Tags: javascript, циклы

У меня есть метод `array.Prototype.sameStructureAs(arr)`, который проверяет структуру вложенности массивов, но у меня возникла проблема с проверкой, если первый элемент массива это просто число.

Вот мой код:

```
Array.prototype.sameStructureAs = function (other) {
if ( Array.isArray(this)&& Array.isArray(other) ) {//Проверка являются ли элементы массивами
    if ( this.length === other.length) {
        for (let i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
            if ( (Array.isArray(this[i]) && Array.isArray(other[i])) && (this[i].length===other[i].length))//Проверка являются ли первые элементы массивов массивами и проверка их длин// {
                for (let j=0; j<this[i].length;j++) {
                    if (Array.isArray(this[i][j]) && Array.isArray(other[i][j])) {
                        return true
                    } else return false
                }
            }if ( ( Array.isArray(this[i]) && !Array.isArray(other[i]) ) || ( !Array.isArray(this[i]) && Array.isArray(other[i]) ) ) {
                return false
        } else if (!Array.isArray(this[i]) && !Array.isArray(other[i])) {
            return true
        }
        }
    }
}
```

};

По задумке последняя строка должна возвращать `true` если все элементы массива - не массивы, но в моей случае так не работает `console.log([1, [1, 1]].sameStructureAs([2,[2]]))` возвращает `true`, хотя должен быть `false`. Как мне сделать так, чтобы после проверки первого элемента, цикл продолжался дальше? Надеюсь понятно объяснил

Comment: "хотя должен быть false" --- где в коде returm false ?

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, тут не весь мой код, а только блок с которым у меня проблема. Главный вопрос в том, как мне продолжить цикл for. Если нужен весь код, я исправлю вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю должно быть что-то типа такого:

```
for (let i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
    if (ЕСЛИ ЭЛЕМЕНТ НЕ МАССИВ)) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Comment: Возможно я не правильно описал суть вопроса, и моего куска кода было недостаточно, я изменил вопрос

Comment: Не знаю. По мне так всё просто - если элемент не является ожидаемым - то сразу return false . Дальнейшие манипуляции не имеют смысла, включая продолжение цикла, если  проверка не прошла...